# Get rid of white space between breakpoints bar and code?in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I am trying to use VS on a smaller screen and use 2 code windows side by side as I'm used to it on the big monitor, very comfy. However the horizontal space is very big problem, removing line numbers helped, but still 10% of the screen estate is occupied with this thing:

[image]

Is there a way to get rid of it? It shows the suggestions popup in there, but I don't need it, after all I have shortcuts to invoke actions, but that huge column is a total waste

Comment: Anyone found any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't completely remove that area but these are the closest options I've been able to find to reduce the size around it.

Go to the Tools Tab>Options>Text Editor>General

Under the "Display" options uncheck the following:

- Selection Margin
- Indicator Margin (This removes the breaks points margin though)

[image]